# Time Complexity Calculation - Is my approach correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, recursion

> Give the running  time in terms of n.

```
 public static void spacejam(int n) {
         if (n <= 1) {
             return;
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
                 spacejam(n - 1);
             }
         }
```

My cost function is calls to spacejam. For n = 4, first there is 1 spacejam(4) call, then there are 4 spacejam(3) calls then 4.3 spacejam(2) calls and finally 4.3.2 spacejam(1) call.

```
current-call work (# of calls made)     i

spacejam(4) 4!/3!                       4

spacejam(3) 4!/2!                       3

spacejam(2) 4!/1!                       2

spacejam(1) 0                           1
```

Generalizing: runtime = total work = $\sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{n!}{(i-1)!} \le n!(1 + \sum_{i=3}^n\dfrac{1}{(i-1)(i-2)}) = n!(2 - \dfrac{1}{n-1}) = O(n!)$

The answer derived in the solution is $O(n*n!)$ (additional n in multiplication) which agrees with my answer $O(n!)$ but I am not sure if that is correct. Could someone verify?

Comment: Is `N` supposed to be the same as `n`? The code looks like C, which is case sensitive, so the function never uses the `int n` argument. Also, the `for` loop never uses the `i` counter.

Comment: @dxiv yes, it's supposed to be the same. I have fixed my post.

Comment: @dxiv The for loop uses i to iterate n times.

Comment: Note: it is not true that $\mathcal O(n!)$ and $\mathcal O(n \times n!)$ are the same (the latter is the same as $\mathcal O((n+1)!)$, though). It is a good exercise to prove this from the definition if it's not (yet) obvious to you.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I know they are not the same. I meant that any function that is O(n!) (my answer) must also be O(n*n!) (given answer). Hence I can't determine if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: @GoldCredential That looks right now. You can also bound the sum by $\,\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!} \lt \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}=e-1\,$.